# Filtering sensitive information from DelayedJob logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, logging, delayed-job

Rails 3 has a nice feature in `config/application.rb` that allows one to filter sensitive information, such as passwords, from appearing in logs, as shown below:

`config.filter_parameters += [:password, :creditcardnum]`

However, my question lies in how to filter that same information from logging elsewhere. For example, I am using DelayedJob, and even though my password is filtered from my development log, it still appears when DelayedJob logs (and I imagine something similar would happen with similarly working gems):

`SQL (14.3ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("attempts", "created_at", "failed_at", "handler", "last_error", "locked_at", "locked_by", "priority", "queue", "run_at", "updated_at") VALUES (blah blah blah...) username: MYUSERNAME@EMAIL.COM\n    password: MYPASSWORDHERE\n method_name: :destroy\nargs: []\n"], ["last_error", nil], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["priority", 0], ["queue", nil], ["run_at", Wed, 03 Jul 2013 03:07:02 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 03 Jul 2013 03:07:02 UTC +00:00]]`

Would you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest sending only non-sensitive information to delayed job.

For example, the following code sends the full `user` object (including password or any other sensitive information) to delayed job:

```rb
user.delay.activate
```

To prevent that, first we can prepare a `ActivateUserJob`:

```rb
class ActivateUserJob < Struct.new(:user_id)
  def perform
    user = User.find(user_id)
    user.activate
  end
end
```

Then, enqueue the job when needed. This way, only the id of the `user` is revealed:

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue ActivateUserJob.new(user.id)
```

Comment: Hi @Domon, my apologies for the delay. I'd like to follow up with you about this to see if you could explain something: What is the difference here between `:user_id`, `user_id`, and `user.id`? I thought that user_id needs to be in quotes (`"user_id"`) to mean the same thing as :user_id, and I don't know what `user.id` means in relation to the other two.